# Can't call method X on an undefined value

Tags: perl, mechanize

Why does the following code produce the error "Can't call method "get" on an undefined value at... line 6"?  I've read through similar posts and think I understand why this sort of error message tends to show up, but I don't see how it applies here.  I copied this code from a tutorial on the WWW::Mechanize module and so I expected it to work out of the can.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings ;
use strict ;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $url = 'http://www.google.com';
my $m->get($url);
my $link = $m->find_link(text =>'Advanced Search');
print "The Google advanced search URL is: $link->url()\n";
```

Comment: You've haven't assigned a value to `$m`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've missed the step of assigning an instance of the `WWW::Mechanize` class to the `$m` variable:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new; # <-- HERE

my $url = 'http://www.google.com';

$m->get($url); # ...and remove 'my' from this line

my $link = $m->find_link(text =>'Advanced Search');

# also, a method call won't interpolate properly, so change
# the below line as well:

print "The Google advanced search URL is: " . $link->url() . "\n";

# or:

# my $result = $link->url();
# print "The Google advanced search URL is: $result\n";
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to solve the problem.  But using your code, I now get an error saying "Can't call method "url" on an undefined valued at...line 14 (the print line).  Does $link need to be assigned as well?  I've tried doing so, but apparently not correctly.

Comment: @Rick Sounds like no link was found, then.

Comment: @melpomene You are correct.  I see the Google home page does not currently have the "Advanced Search" link, and when I update the link then stevieb's code works as expected.

Comment: @Rick You could simply wrap the `$link` code and the printing of the results within an if/else block... `if (defined $link){...}else{print "no link found"}`

Comment: I had this error connected when I called a routine from a package, which had no sub keywords listed in front of routines names.